# Sqlite Insert statement not running

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have the following code for my sqlite to store a name and image from camera. I know from the Eclipse console that I am getting the name and image path. The console.log(addRecord) is getting the name and image path but I am getting a "cannot executeSql of undefined" message on the transaction line and on the queryDB function so I think I am making a mistake with my insert statement? Also, is the datatype text correct for imageURI?. Any help appreciated.

```
   function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("database", "1.0", "Profiles", 5000);
    if(db) {
console.log('The device is ready');
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB, insertRecord); // only do stuff if db exists
}
else{
console.log('There is a problem');
}   
   function populateDB(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERS');//get rid of this once working?
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username VARCHAR NOT NULL, imagePath TEXT)');
   console.log('The table USERS is created');
   }
  //Insert the details
function insertRecord(tx) {
       userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
       imagePath;
       var addRecord = 'INSERT INTO USERS (username, imagePath) VALUES ("' + userName + '","' + imagePath + '")';
       console.log(addRecord);
       tx.executeSql(addRecord, [userName, imagePath], queryDB, errorCB);
}

 // Query the database
function queryDB(tx) {
       var getUsers = "SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY id ASC', [], querySuccess, errorCB";
       db.transaction(function (tx) {
       tx.executeSql(getUsers, [], querySuccess, queryFailure);
    }, errorCB, successCB);
}

// Query the success callback

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        console.log("You are in the querysuccess function");
}

// Transaction error callback

function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}

function queryFailure(err) {
      console.log("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}
// Transaction success callback

function successCB() {
      console.log('The db and table are working');
 }
```

Comment: You're not showing the code that calls `insertRecord`.

Comment: I have included that now (I think!).

Comment: That is not how transactions work. The first callback passed to `transaction` has to perform all the work, after it completes the transaction is committed (or it can be already rolled back by an error). There is no way `insertRecord` is being called in that code, you are calling it from elsewhere (probably from an event handler in a form submit) and not passing a transaction.

Comment: Or is this what you mean? <input id="saveProfile" type="button" value="Save" onClick="insertRecord();""location.href='Createtask.html'"> <br>

Comment: Yes. Look at it, you're calling it with no parameters, but the function signature says you should pass the transaction. Fix the signature and explicitly create a transaction inside `insertRecord` to insert that row.

Comment: OK so I think I have done that correctly <input id="saveProfile" type="button" value="Save" onClick="insertRecord(tx);""location.href='Createtask.html'"> However, I am now getting a tx undefined error. Totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier `queryFailure` is undefined. Add the function:

```
function queryFailure(tx, results) {
    console.log("You are in the queryFailure function");
}
```

Once you get it running, you will see that the `queryFailure` function is called, because you have an error in the query. This:

```
var getUsers = "SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY id ASC', [], querySuccess, errorCB";
```

should be:

```
var getUsers = "SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Comment: Thanks, it will be useful when I need to handle that part.